# Linker chooses "wrong" main with Boost.Test

Tags: program-entry-point, static-linking, libpng, boost-test

When using Boost.Test, there is generally no need to define a `main()` function, since Boost.Test provides one itself.

I recently had to convert my project to use static linking of 3rd party libraries (on VS2010). Naturally, I had to link to multiple `.lib`s so that the build succeeds, and my build ran just fine.

However, when I ran my test project, something really strange happened. It seems that one of the 3rd party `.lib`s (libpng), required by one of my dependent libraries, contained a test file with a `main()` function defined within (`pngtest.c`, if you must know).
Since my project did not have a `main()` function, the linker chose that one as my "test" application. Thus, non of my tests run.

Does anyone know how I prevent this from happening? How can I tell the linker/compiler to use the Boost.Test `main()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, and clarifying @Tom's answer.
Turns out that the `libpng` build script I was using was not the the original shipping with `libpng` but one created by the OpenCV build system. The file `pngtest.c` was mistakenly included int the build.

The solution to the problem was to remove `pngtest.c` from the libpng build script.
The latest OpenCV version, does not include this file anymore.

For more details see [my post to Boost mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/75360) here and my [OpenCV bug report here](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2322).

Answer (score 1):

Adi, I had the same problem.  Looks like you were already all over this one.  Thanks to Google and your efforts, I was able to figure it out.

Here's some info to round out the answer:

- discussion:
  http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-Test-Linker-chooses-wrong-main-function-td4634872.html
- solution:
  http://code.opencv.org/issues/2322

Basically, I just excluded the `pngtest.c` file from the libpng project, and recompiled OpenCV.  Looks like it will be fixed in the next release of OpenCV.

Thanks!